# Problems with Chrome css and iframe

Tags: css, google-chrome, iframe

I'm managing this site: (no joke)

http://www.orgasmatrix.fr/webcams

As you can see, when you put your mouse over "Categories" the menu appears below the iframe called "chat_".
I have search about it. I have read and test with "position:absolute" and "z-index:-999", but no way.
I have found another tip with the iframe embenbed and try to put "?wmode=transparent" or "?wmode=opaque" as a parameter.
Also I have tested with , and also with the atributte allowtransparency="true". But no way, the iframe always appear above the "Categories" menu.

Any help?
I'll be very grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't with your code, but deeper - in very nested iframe (I have counted 3) with that chat element:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://img.media-rendering2.com/market2/livecams/chat_coquin/chat_v2.swf" wmode="transparent" width="300" height="405" id="chatCoquinTac" style="visibility: visible; "><param name="menu" value="false"><param name="quality" value="high"><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"><param name="wmode" value="transparent"><param name="flashvars" value="url_acces=&amp;url_image=http%3A%2F%2Fimg.media-rendering2.com%2Fmarket2%2Flivecams%2Fchat_coquin%2F&amp;sexe=h&amp;langue=fr&amp;webcam=7&amp;pseudo=Julia&amp;ville=Warsaw&amp;format=2&amp;temps=1338679111"></object>
```

As you can see I have added (with developer tools) `<param name="wmode" value="transparent">` and `wmode="transparent"` to `<object>` and it worked as it should (Chrome 19) - your categories menu appears above chat window.

Comment: Great :) Could you approve the answer please?

Comment: I meant "accept" when I wrote "approve", I can't edit because it's too late.

Comment: One qüestion.Is it possible to have the same result using jquery?

Comment: I'm not sure, because you serve a content from other domains in your `iframe`. Besides, you're using very old version of jQuery (1.4.2), latest is 1.7.2.

Comment: If you do not mind, do you have any link where i can see the code? Thanks

Comment: The jQuery code to show the menu above all the other things. Thanks